# how to style specific run through of an iterator using css

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts2

I have this iterator on one of my pages is there a way I can style a certain run through of the iterator such as making the first run through in a container 400 by 200px and the next run through in a different container around 200 by 200px?

```
<s:iterator value="walkthroughs">
    <div>
        <span>
            <s:property default="fail" value="_walkthroughText"/>
        </span> 
     </div> 
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: So, it's a strut2 question, right? You should tag it as such. mysql doesn't have anything to do with your question, though.

Comment: what do you mean for 200 by 200px and 200 by 400px, are they the height and width?

Answer (score 1):

From the [iterator tag documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/iterator.html):

> status - If specified, an instanceof IteratorStatus will be pushed into stack upon each iteration

For example:

```
<s:iterator value="#it.days" status="rowstatus">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true">
      <td style="background: grey"><s:property/></td>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
      <td><s:property/></td>
    </s:else>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

[Here is the Javadoc of IteratorStatus](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html).

Comment: it there is more then two objects (there are five) would I simply

   'code'( <s:iterator value="#it.days" status="rowstatus">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="#rowstatus.?one? == true">
      <td style="background: grey"><s:property/></td>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
      <td><s:property/></td>
    </s:else>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>)

Comment: Look at the javadoc for IteratorStatus. There is no `isOne()` method. There is a method `isFirst()` though. So it should be `<s:if test="#rowStatus.first == true">`

Comment: ok and the next would be <s:if text="#rowStatus.second == true">

Comment: you are making a funny dialog :D just use `<s:if test="#rowStatus.index == 2">`, forget `first`,`second`, `etc...`

Comment: Fort christ sake, read the javadoc. Is there an `isSecond()` method in IteratorStatus? Which other method could you use to test if the index is the second one? If you never read any documentation, you won't learn much.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I have been fighting with this for two days. I am trying to implement it now.

Comment: think for two days and do nothing shouldn't be a good idea for programming o_o

Comment: @user1698308 If you've been fighting with this for two days I'd suggest you're not fighting correctly--take a step back, try to develop some awareness of what you're doing and the environment in which you're doing it, and stop trying random combinations of characters, keywords, operators, etc.